# O que são Máscara de Rede, Gateway e como eles se relacionam com o modem/roteador?

Tags: redes

Acho que a indagação mais precisa seria: "Como ocorre uma conexão cliente/host desde a saída do pacote do cliente, passando pela rede interna, saindo pelo modem até chegar no host e onde se encaixa exatamente o papel de cada um desses itens nesse processo?".

Comment: O titulo é simples: Gateway é o dispositivo que conecta essa rede (interna) à internet, máscara de rede é o padrão pra definir IPs (255 = todos os IPS tem o mesmo numero ali). Redes de até se n me engano 254 computadores costumam usar a mascara 255.255.255.0 que permite somente o ultimo bloco diferente de um computador pro outro. Como se relacionam, bem, aí eu vou montar uma resposta decente mais tarde se ninguém tiver explicado melhor. :D

Answer (score 1):

Máscara de Rede, resumidamente são a quantidade de Ips que um equipamento pode tomar dentro daquela rede, ou seja, se a Máscara for 255.255.255.0, poderás ter 255 atribuidos, sendo que dois são reservados ao Broadcast e ao Gateway.
O Gateway e o roteator podem ser a mesma coisa.